# Find total number of records in a database EF4.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Anyone know how to get the total number of records in a database using EF 4.1?  I have looked at the documentation but can't find anything that isn't summing the .Count() for each table.

(I have lots of tables and am changing the number during design so this isn't appropriate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do count for each table. There is no way to get such information other way with EF and I'm not sure if other tools provide it.